# Recommended approach & tools to provision a VM instance(s) from node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, puppet, vagrant

I am trying to implement a '**lab in the cloud**' to allow people to have a sandbox to experiment and learn in; i.e. for devops (chef/puppet), installing or configuring software etc.
I have a node.js server implementation to manage this and looking for sane and reasonable ways to attack this problem.

The options are bewilderingly diverse: puppet or chef directly, or vagrant seems appropriate. But Openstack, cloudfoundry, Amazon EC2 also provide their own feature sets.
Ideally a micro-cloud solution (multiple VM's per instance) would be ideal as there isn't going to be any large computational load.

Suggestions most appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, it seems that LXC on EC2 might be the way forward:

It gives

1. lightweight, instances on a single EC2 instance
2. supports hibernate/restore
3. fast to standup
4. able to automate using chef/cucumber

[EC2 virtualization using LXC](http://www.activestate.com/blog/2011/10/virtualization-ec2-cloud-using-lxc)

[Chef-lxc](https://github.com/niklas/chef-lxc)

[Testing infrastructure code in LXC using Cucumber](https://github.com/exceedhl/toft)